# Should jQuery mouseout event "unhover" css elements?

Tags: jquery

Some elements have `:hover` css attributes and I need them to be taken away by forcing mouseout `.trigger("mouseout");` Should not it be working?

Answer (score 1):

Forcing a mouseout event will not remove the `:hover` pseudoclass, the browser is responsible for that.

Perhaps you want to bind event handlers that add a class on mouseover and remove the class on mouseout. Then you'd have finer grained control over when the class is added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. The implementation of most rendering engines to not tie the activation/deactivation of the hover state to the mouse-out/over events. Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Try asking for an alternative, but give more information. You should get what you want that way.